# Explain: Don't communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating

Tags: go, memory, channel, goroutine

I wonder what is the most down to earth explanation of this famous quote:

> Don't communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating. (R. Pike)

In [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) I can read this:

> A send on a channel happens before the corresponding receive from that channel completes. (Golang Spec)

There is also a dedicated [golang article](https://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating) explaining the quote. And key contribution is a [working example](https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/sharemem/) also by Andrew G.

Well. Sometimes too much talking around .... I have derived from the Memory Spec quotation and also by looking at the working example this:

> After a goroutine1 sends (anything) to a goroutine2 via a channel, then all changes (anywhere in the memory) done by goroutine1 must be visible to goroutine2 after it received via same channel. (Golang Lemma by Me:)

Therfore I derive the Down to earth explanation of the famous quote:

> To synchronize memory access between two goroutines, you don't need to send that memory via channel. Good enough is to receive from the channel (even nothing). You will see any changes that were written (anywhere) by the goroutine sending (to the channel) at the time of it's send. (Of course, assuming no other goroutines are writing to the same memory.) **Update (2) 8-26-2017**

I have actually two questions:

**1) Is my conclusion correct?**

**2) Does my explanation help?**

**Update (1)**
I am assuming *unbuffered channels*. Lets restrict ourselves to that first to avoid overhauling ourselves with too many unknowns.

Please, let's also focus on a simple usecase of two goroutines communicating over a single channel and related memory effects and not on the best practices - that is beyond the scope of this question.

To better understand scope of my question assume that the goroutines may access  any kind of memory structure - not only primitve ones - and it can be a large one, it can be a string, map, array, whatever.

Comment: Did Rob Pike say this in a publication? What is a good citation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In essence, yes. Any values that are assigned to variables before the channel send are eligible to be observed after the channel read, since the channel operation imposes an ordering constraint. But it's important to remember the other part of the equation: if you want to *guarantee* that those values are observed, you have to make sure that no one else can write to those variables in between the write and the read. Obviously using locks would be possible, but pointless at the same time because if you're already combining locks and cross-thread memory modification, what benefit are you getting from channels? You could pass around something as simple as a boolean, as a token allowing exclusive access to the global data, and it would be 100% correct in terms of the memory model guarantees (as long as your code didn't have bugs), *it would just probably be a bad design* because you would be making things all implicit and action-at-a-distance-y without a good reason; passing the data explicitly is usually going to be clearer and less error-prone.

Comment: So far this addresses most the point of my question. Thx. Still waiting for Rob P. to say his part though:)

Answer (score 55):

This famous quote can be a little bit confusing if taken too litterally. Let's break it down to its more basic components, and define them properly:

```
Don't communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating
      ---- 1 ----    ------ 2 -----  ---- 3 -----    ----- 4 -----
```

1. This means that different threads of execution would be informed of the change of state of other threads by reading memory that would be modified somewhere else.
   A perfect example of this (although for processes instead of threads) is the POSIX shared memory API: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html.
   This technique needs proper synchronization because data races can occur pretty easily.
2. Here this means that there is indeed a portion of memory, physical or virtual, that can be modified from several threads, and read from those, too. There is no explicit notion of ownership, the memory space is equally accessible from all threads.
3. This is entirely different. In Go, sharing memory just like above is possible, and data races can occur pretty easily, so what this actually means is, modifying a variable in a goroutine, be it a simple value like an `int` or a complicated data structure like a map, and give away ownership by sending the value or a pointer to the value to a different goroutine via the channel mechanism. So ideally, there is no shared space, each goroutine only sees the portion of memory it owns.
4. Communication here simply means that a channel, which is only a queue, allows one goroutine to read from it and so be notified of the ownership of a new portion of memory, while another one sends it and accepts to lose ownership. It is a simple message passing pattern.

In conclusion, what the quote means can be summed up like this:

> Don't overengineer inter-thread communication by using shared memory and complicated, error-prone synchronisation primitives, but instead use message-passing between goroutines (green threads) so variables and data can be used in sequence between those.

The use of the word sequence here is noteworthy, because it describes the philosophy that inspired the concept of goroutines and channels: [Communicating Sequential Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes).

Comment: Thanks for your contributiuon @SirDarius. So far this question I asked is causing me lots of fun:) I hope to everyone else too. But, is your answer to my questions 1) No 2) No ?

Comment: I would say, yes, and yes, even though I'm not sure the phrasing of your conclusion sounds "idiomatic" for Go developers, if you see what I mean. The thing that is missing is essentially the notion of passing of ownership.

Comment: This part in your answer is really misleading: "...and give away ownership by sending the value or a pointer to the value to a different goroutine via the channel mechanism" - there is not concept of ownership in go and in fact supposing so leads to race condition if sending goroutine modifies data again.

Comment: Since there is effectively no notion of ownership, this is down to best practices indeed, which you stated your question is not about. However I'd argue that "share memory by communicating" is a guideline for best practices, specifically, _don't reuse variables that you sent through a  channel_.

Answer (score 8):

Let me go simple and to the point here.

> Don't communicate by sharing memory.

It is like when your are communicating using threads for example you have to use variables or mutexes to lock memory for not allowing someone to read and write on it until the communication is complete.

> Share memory by communicating

In go routines values move on channels rather than blocking the memory, sender notifies receiver to receive from that channel and hence it share memory by communicating with receiver to get from a channel.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think so.  The gist is instead of protecting one fixed memory address with a lock or other concurrent primitives, you can architect the program in a way that only one stream of execution is allowed to access this memory *by design*.

The easy way to achieve this is to share the reference to the memory by channels. 
Once you send the reference over the channel you *forget it*. In this way only the routine that will consume that channel will have access to it.

Comment: Yes, the gist was about something completely else - as you describe in your second paragraph. But if I am wrong where I am wrong then?.

Answer (score 7):

There are two sentences in this; for fuller understanding these must be looked separately first, and then clubbed together, So:
`Don't communicate by sharing memory;` means, different threads should not communicate with each other by complying to the stringent and error-prone memory visibility and synchronization policies like memory barrier etc. (Note that it can be done, but it can soon become complex and very buggy with data races). So avoid complying to manual, programmatic visibility constructs mostly attained thru proper synchronizations in programming languages like Java.

`share memory by communicating.` means if one thread has made any changes (writes) to a memory area, it should communicate the same (the memory area) to the thread interested in that same memory area; note this has already restricted the scope of memory to only two threads.

Now read the above two paragraphs in conjunction with the golang memory model which says, `A send on a channel happens before the corresponding receive from that channel completes.` The happens-before relationship confirms that the write by first goroutine will-be visible to the second goroutine receiving the memory reference at the other end of the channel!

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is my conclusion correct?

I think so, if it means what I hope it does. The reason for the language in the specs using the "happenstance" terminology is that it provides a well defined form of communication for expressing ideas.

The problem with your description is that you haven't actually explicitly defined your happenstance order. I think though that you are implying an order. If you mean that "operations in goroutine a that happen before goroutine a operates on a particular point of synchronization will be visible by goroutine b after goroutine b has also observed that same point of synchronization" - even here though, the "point of synchronization" is poorly defined - though I expect you understand it. Such a point can be defined in happenstance, as the specification does.

> 2) Does my explanation help?

Maybe, people unfamiliar with the topic or that are struggling with understanding the happenstance style of description may find your description easier to interpret. There are however limitations and potential practical problems in the application your description, as follows:

- You have not strictly defined that the "send" you are talking about is a synchronization point. If you mean a send on an unbuffered channel, then yes, that will create a shared synchronization point that by specification introduces a strict happenstance order.
- While, assuming the above is true, you have described a synchronization point, this only addresses one side of the point of the original advice. The original advice includes the concept of "transfer of ownership", and that has less to do with creating synchronization points or happenstance, and more to do with the longer term maintenance of code that relies on potentially shared memory. The concept is that instead of retaining access to some segment of memory in two places, and creating separate shared synchronization points (like mutexes), one can instead pass, possibly the only, reference to the object from one owner to another. Designing software this way prevents the accidental modification outside of synchronization points, which has often been observed in software with granular use of mutexes and extensive use of shared memory.

Mutexes or "explicit synchronization points" are exactly the opposite of the advice - they are a shared piece of memory that is used to communicate a synchronization point "communicate by sharing memory", whereas, even though they have mutexes deep under the hood, channels are an abstract mechanism to pass ownership of an object (the sent value) from one goroutine (sender) to another goroutine (receiver). The point there is, ignoring how channels are implemented, that the user has shared memory (the value) by communicating it from one owner (goroutine a) to another (goroutine b). If you are using a channel to send unrelated data to create a synchronization point, you're essentially using it as a mutex, and this is closer to communicate by sharing memory (focus on the channel), rather than sharing by communicating (focus on the value).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out buffered channels! I have updated my question so that it is obvious that I was assuming unbuffered channels in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

1. communicate by sharing memory:
   this is the "traditional" way to deal with multithreading. If some data is shared by two threads, to keep them from for example attempting to write both at the same time, some synchronization primitives must be used. This is notoriously difficult to debug. It is interesting to keep in mind that in time sharing, the processor is allocating a time slice (for example 100ms) to one thread, and then switches context, and allocates the next time slice to another thread. The switch happens while the operating system has no knowledge of what the code run by the threads is doing. If operations aren't atomic, they can be interrupted by the operating system at any step.
2. share memory by communicating:
   Typically, this is the case using an actor model where each actor is mapped to a processor core. Actors exchange messages using a mailbox system where the receiver receives a copy of the message. There is no shared data, so no need for synchronization mechanisms like mutexes. Another name for this architecture is "shared nothing".