# Is leaked memory freed up when the program exits in golang?

Tags: go

Before you claim a repeat [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975831/is-leaked-memory-freed-up-when-the-program-exits), I've read all those answers, but my question is focus to golang specific.
With the golang proverb [Don't communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating](https://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating) I wonder if there is a different by how golang manage the memory

Comment: Please go through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44484602/5821354 for your question on `Don't communicate by sharing memory`

Comment: It's a duplicate anyway, although I can't find the other question now. Yes, memory is freed unless there's a serious bug in your operating system. This has nothing to do at all with Go.

Comment: This is a direct duplicate of the question linked, as the accepted answer there clearly and explicitly provides a general, non-language specific answer, which obviously applies to Go as well.

Comment: Apart from the fact that the word memory is used in both topics, the topics are essentially unrelated.

Comment: well, I explained why I thought that, you didn't need to downvote my question. What you think is an obvious topic, may no be that obvious for someone else

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears you should refine your knowledge of how contemporary computer systems work—this may help working with languages such as Go, which are reasonably "closer to the metal" than some other mainstream solutions.

The thing is, the commodity platforms current Go runs on (except maybe WebAssembly—which runs on a high-level VM typically provided by a web browser) do two things related to the problem in question: fully "contain" the processes they're executing, and provide to them the so-called
[virtual memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

The former means a process running by the kernel of a commodity
OS (Linux- or *BSD-based, Windows, Mac OS X etc) has no way to
do anything useful without asking the underlying kernel to do that
*on behalf of that process.* That is, the process does not actually allocate a memory or open a file or send bytes over a TCP socket—it asks the kernel to do so.

As a result, the kernel has full and exact account of all the resources allocated to each of the processes it manages.
Consequently, when a process finishes executing for some reason,
the kernel cleans up after it: closes file and socket descriptors
which are still open, deallocates other resources and *reclaims
the memory* which was committed to the process.

So the direct answer to your question is: of course, yes,
and this does not in any way depend on how a process was
implemented (that is, has it been written in C or in Go
or in Java—and hence was run by the Java VM and compiled on
the fly from the byte codes to real CPU instructions, or in JavaScript and executed by Node.js, or in Python—and hence the
kernel wasn't actually executing your Python code but actually
the Python interpreter's code, and so on and so on)—the kernel
does not even "see" all these differences as it executes
CPU instructions and performs
the [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)
made by the processes (again, using CPU instructions).

---

The remaining part, which is only tangentially related to
the essence of your question, but anyway may be helpful to
think about is that of memory management.

The thing is, if we consider a process executing a program
written in Go which is running on one of operating systems
Go supports, there exist *two levels* of memory management:

1. The low-level, provided by the kernel, and
2. The high-level, provided by the Go runtime (which is
   linked to any running program written in Go).

The Go program asks the Go runtime which powers it to allocate
memory, when needed, and the garbage collector, which again
is a part of the Go runtime, from time to time reclaims
the memory which got unused back to the memory pool maintained
by the runtime. In essence, the memory which gets "freed"
while a Go program is running stays within the program,
and when it is needed again, the Go runtime will try to
allocate it from its pool.

Only when the Go runtime's memory manager has not enough free
memory, will it reach for the OS and allocate memory there—thus
engaging that another layer of memory management.

Surely, the memory does not only flow from the kernel to the
Go runtime: the latter has a mechanism to mark memory pages
which stay free for too long as unused so that the kernel is
free to reclaim them back when it sees fit (typically when
the system gets under a memory pressure).

---

I'd say, you should read a book or two on how a typical operating
system works.

Comment: could you recommend a book to it?