# Package "fmt" runtime issue

Tags: go, runtime, panic

I encounter a problem that seems simple but that I cannot reproduce, and therefore that I cannot explain.

This problem occurs in production, what is mysterious is that it occurs very rarely (that's why I can't reproduce it), it may be a factor that I could not set out as an example but here is the context:

```
type MyType struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
    Field3 time.Time
    Field4 []float64
    // No pointers fields
}

func main() {
    var MyChan = make(chan interface{})

    go func() {
// This routine is reading and parsing messages from a WS dial and writing it in a channel
// There is 2 only possible answer in the channel : a string, or a "MyType" like (with more fields, but no pointers in)     
        var Object MyType
        Object.Field1 = "test"
        // ..

        MyChan <- Object
    }()

    go func() {
// This routine is sending a message to a WS dial and wait for the answer in a channel fed by another routine :
        var Object interface{}
        go func(Get *interface{}) {
            *Get = <- MyChan
        } (&Object)
        for Object == nil {
            time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond * 1)
        }
        log.Println(fmt.Sprint(Object)) // Panic here from the fmt.Sprint() func
    }()
}
```

Panic stack trace :

```
runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
panic(0x87a840, 0xd0ff40)
    X:/Go/GoRoot/src/runtime/panic.go:522 +0x1b5
reflect.Value.String(0x85a060, 0x0, 0xb8, 0xc00001e500, 0xc0006f1a80)
    X:/Go/GoRoot/src/reflect/value.go:1781 +0x45
fmt.(*pp).printValue(0xc006410f00, 0x85a060, 0x0, 0xb8, 0x76, 0x1)
    X:/Go/GoRoot/src/fmt/print.go:747 +0x21c3
fmt.(*pp).printValue(0xc006410f00, 0x8ed5c0, 0x0, 0x99, 0x76, 0x0)
    X:/Go/GoRoot/src/fmt/print.go:796 +0x1b52
fmt.(*pp).printArg(0xc006410f00, 0x8ed5c0, 0x0, 0x76)
    X:/Go/GoRoot/src/fmt/print.go:702 +0x2ba
fmt.(*pp).doPrint(0xc006410f00, 0xc0006f22a0, 0x1, 0x1)
    X:/Go/GoRoot/src/fmt/print.go:1147 +0xfd
fmt.Sprint(0xc0006f22a0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    X:/Go/GoRoot/src/fmt/print.go:250 +0x52
```

**Go version : 1.12.1 windows/amd64**

Thanking you for your time, I hope someone can explain to me what's wrong.

Comment: Assigning to *Get races against the for condition right after. Race conditions make the behavior of your program undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a data race here:

> ```
>     var Object interface{}
>     go func(Get *interface{}) {
>         *Get = <- MyChan
>     } (&Object)
>     for Object == nil {
>         time.Sleep(time.Nanosecond * 1)
>     }
> ```

The goroutine that writes on the variable `Object` does so without using a lock: it receives from the channel, and when it gets a value, it writes it to `*Get` where `Get == &Object`, so that it writes the interface value of `Object`.

Meanwhile, the goroutine running the `for` loop reads from `Object`, checking for nil-ness.  It reads without using a lock, so that it can read a partially-written value.

What is actually happening is that the partially-written value is non-nil, without the whole value being set.  So the `for` loop stops looping and the code progresses to the next line:

> ```
>     log.Println(fmt.Sprint(Object)) // Panic here from the fmt.Sprint() func
> ```

Since `Object` is only *partly* written, accessing its value produces unpredictable results—but in this case, it produces a panic.  (In particular, the *type* field of the interface has been set, but the *value* field is still zero.  The actual panic is from this line in `src/reflect/value.go`:

> > ```
> >                return *(*string)(v.ptr)
> > ```

with `v.ptr` not having been set.)

It's not clear why you're logging the value at all, nor why you are using shared memory to communicate, but if you *do* do this, you will need locking.  It's usually wiser not to do this.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44484602/1256452) to [Explain: Don't communicate by sharing memory; share memory by communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36391421/1256452).

(Or, to put it more simply, why not just use `Object := <-MyChan` in place of the whole goroutine-and-spin?)

Comment: There is stuff between the goroutine and the `for Object == nil {}`, but indeed, you exposed an error which implies to completely review this method. I will follow your advice for memory sharing.